# Eclemma: Invalid Input Url Error in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, eclemma

After starting Eclipe I see the following error message in the workspace/.metadata/.log

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.runtime 4 0 2017-09-18 09:38:48.275 
!MESSAGE Invalid input url:platform:/plugin/com.mountainminds.eclemma.ui/icons/full/eview16/coverage.gif 
!STACK 0 
java.io.IOException: Unable to resolve plug-in "platform:/plugin/com.mountainminds.eclemma.ui/icons/full/eview16/coverage.gif".
```

The message does not go away even after uninstalling or reinstalling the plugin.
Any ideas on how to resolve this?

Eclipse: Oxygen 4.7.0  
EclEmma: 3.0.0

Comment: Did you install Eclipse Oxygen from scratch or update an older Eclipse version to Oxygen? EclEmma are now an Eclipse project and part of the Eclipse Java download packages. Because of this names of plug-ins and packages changed (EclEmma 3.0.0 does not contain a plug-in `com.mountainminds.eclemma.ui`, but the plug-in `org.eclipse.eclemma.ui`)

Comment: I did install Oxygen from scratch - I do have the org.eclipse.eclemma.ui jarfile. - I use a workspace I set up with an older version of eclipse though ...

Comment: Does starting Eclipse with the option "-clean" solve the issue?

Comment: No, starting with "-clean" does not solve it.

Comment: Yeah, the workspace seems to be the issue, probably something in the ./metadata ... when I start a new workspace there is no such message

Comment: Maybe the stored window layout contains an invalid reference to the icon. Does a reset of the perspective fix the issue?

Comment: Yes, that did indeed remove the error - thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EclEmma became an Eclipse project and is now part of the Eclipse Java download packages. Due to the move, the plug-ins have been rename: `com.mountainminds.eclemma.ui` become `org.eclipse.eclemma.ui`.

If you use a **workspace** that have been used **with EclEmma < 3.0.0 before**,

- **start Eclipse with the option `-clean`** and
- **reset all Java perspectives** (`coverage.gif` is the icon of the *Coverage* view and could be referenced in the stored window/perspective layout).

Answer (score 0):

This is the [image](https://github.com/jacoco/eclemma/blob/797c5a0068df8c2e42cf1bec279db30acba7083b/com.mountainminds.eclemma.ui/icons/full/eview16/coverage.gif) the error is referring to.

Put it in the proper installation path on your machine and you'd be fine.

Comment: I installed the plugin via the eclipse marketplace - what I have is a com.eclipse.eclemma.ui - jarfile ... I am not sure where to put the .gif. Is this not supposed to come with the plugin?

Comment: AFAIK, looking at this [PR](https://github.com/eclipse/eclemma/pull/12/files) on their Github repo, the file your installation is referring to has been removed. However try to take a look here:  `<your eclipse installation>/dropins/eclemma-x.y.z/plugins/`

Comment: I see - thanks for the info/suggestion - my dropins folder is empty though